# Executing this VBA code for only the visible data after filtering

Tags: excel, vba

I need this code to only run on the filtered data in the excel sheet. Help!
This code pings IP addresses in one column an outputs the result in another column, now I need to to only run on the IP addresses that are visual after filtering. If anyone knows what to add in order to achieve this , it will be a great help.

```
    Function GetPingResult(Host)

       Dim objPing As Object
       Dim objStatus As Object
       Dim strResult As String

       Set objPing = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}"). _
           ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_PingStatus Where Address = '" & Host & "'")

       For Each objStatus In objPing
          Select Case objStatus.StatusCode
             Case 0: strResult = "Connected"
             Case 11001: strResult = "Buffer too small"
             Case 11002: strResult = "Destination net unreachable"
             Case 11003: strResult = "Destination host unreachable"
             Case 11004: strResult = "Destination protocol unreachable"
             Case 11005: strResult = "Destination port unreachable"
             Case 11006: strResult = "No resources"
             Case 11007: strResult = "Bad option"
             Case 11008: strResult = "Hardware error"
             Case 11009: strResult = "Packet too big"
             Case 11010: strResult = "Request timed out"
             Case 11011: strResult = "Bad request"
             Case 11012: strResult = "Bad route"
             Case 11013: strResult = "Time-To-Live (TTL) expired transit"
             Case 11014: strResult = "Time-To-Live (TTL) expired reassembly"
             Case 11015: strResult = "Parameter problem"
             Case 11016: strResult = "Source quench"
             Case 11017: strResult = "Option too big"
             Case 11018: strResult = "Bad destination"
             Case 11032: strResult = "Negotiating IPSEC"
             Case 11050: strResult = "General failure"
             Case Else: strResult = "Unknown host"
          End Select
          GetPingResult = strResult
       Next

       Set objPing = Nothing

    End Function

    Sub GetIPStatus()

      Dim Cell As Range
      Dim ipRng As Range
      Dim Result As String
      Dim Wks As Worksheet


    Set Wks = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Set ipRng = Wks.Range("F2")
    Set RngEnd = Wks.Cells(Rows.Count, ipRng.Column).End(xlUp)
    Set ipRng = IIf(RngEnd.Row < ipRng.Row, ipRng, Wks.Range(ipRng, RngEnd))

      For Each Cell In ipRng
        Result = GetPingResult(Cell)
        test = IsEmpty(Cell.Value)
        If test = True Then
            Cell.Offset(0, 3) = "No IP Address"
            Result = "No IP Address"
        Else
            Cell.Offset(0, 3) = Result
        End If

        If Result = "Connected" Then
            Cell.Offset(0, 3).Font.Color = vbGreen
        Else
            Cell.Offset(0, 3).Font.Color = vbRed

        End If
      Next Cell

    End Sub
```

Comment: Use `Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`.

Comment: where exactly would I put this line? Literally just started doing vba an hour ago

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.specialcells).

Change

```
For Each Cell In ipRng
```

to

```
For Each Cell in ipRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```